# Adding jquery.gantt to NAPA app

Tags: apps-development, office-365

I trying to add the jquery.gantt ( http://mbielanczuk.com/2011/06/jquery-gantt-chart/) chart to an O365 app created by using NAPA.

For the moment the example doesn't want to load.

Where should I put the js files in my default.aspx and what to put in app.js?

Comment: Can you explain more about the error you are getting? Right now it's nearly impossible to give you advice as we can't even be sure what the specific problem is.

Comment: Napa apps are quite difficult to debug. I don't get any error at all, just blank content where the chart should appear. I'm going to try to import the app to VS and see if I can do some more debugging from there...

Comment: If your js is executing you should be able to debug through the browsers development tools